# Delete multiple columns from pandas dataframe by passing keywords

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which contains almost 1000 columns. I want to delete columns whose names start with tran, can, cad. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html), [`Series.str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), `~` is for invert boolean mask:

```
np.random.seed(100)
c = ['Tran1','t tran','aaa','can','Cad14']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5)), columns=c)
print (df)
   Tran1  t tran  aaa  can  Cad14
0      8       8    3    7      7
1      0       4    2    5      2
2      2       2    1    0      8
3      4       0    9    6      2
4      4       1    5    3      4

mask = df.columns.str.lower().str.startswith(('tran','can','cad'))
#another solution
#mask = df.columns.str.contains('^tran|^can|^cad', case=False)
print (mask)
[ True False False  True  True]

print (~mask)
[False  True  True False False]

df1 = df.loc[:, ~mask]
print (df1)
   t tran  aaa
0       8    3
1       4    2
2       2    1
3       0    9
4       1    5
```

Comment: @jazrael is it case sensitive. Because certain situations can can be Can and same for all

Comment: @jazrael This keywords can be anywhere in column name with upper or lower case... Can you help me on that

Comment: @MebinThomas - Use `mask = df.columns.str.contains('tran|can|cad', case=False)` - removed `^` for match start of string

Answer (score 0):

Just adjust the regex to match case-sensitive or any other demand

```
import re

col_reg = "tran|can|cad"
df = df.drop([x for x in df.columns if re.search(col_reg,x)],axis=1)
```